# Batched version of gradient calculation

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I would like to implement following equation, which sums up the gradients of the output of sample $x_{i}$ wrt a parameter $ \theta_{j} $
$$
\frac{1}{N}\cdot\sum_{i}^{N}\left \| \frac{\partial {F(x_{i},\vec{\theta})}}{\partial {\theta_{j}}} \right \|
$$
Currently I'm doing a single forward pass of one sample, back-propagate, take the L1/L2 norm and accumulate that.

But I would like to make this more efficient by using batches. Is it possible to input multiple samples into the network and than make a single backward pass?

Comment: why do you sum the norm of the gradients?

Comment: This is an equation from a paper to calculate the weight importances

Comment: Can you share it if you dont mind?

Comment: sure: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09601